# Image React-native not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

Iam trying to do this:

```
<Image
  style={styles.image}
  source={require(`./img/${params.image}.png`)}
/>
```

but returns me this error: "Unknown named module[image]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also faced this issue, you can not call image like

```
source={require(`./img/${params.image}.png`)}
```

you have to use another variable to store path and then call it (including `require`)

For example:

```
let imagePath = require("../../assets/list.png");
```

Also note that [you can not call variable into require](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7015).

check this ref. url: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481

Answer (score 3):

Try importing your image at top like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import bgimg from "./assets/bg.jpg";
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<Image source={bgimg}>
```

If this doesn't work, can you please share the directory structure, please show the location of the file you are doing the `require` and the location of this image in the directory structure.